Calling procedures before defining them
Is it ok to call a Guile procedure before defining it? Or is it considered bad programming style?

If you call a procedure before defining it, you'll get an error. Do you mean is it OK to define a procedure that calls a procedure that hasn't been defined yet? Of course, otherwise you couldn't define procedures that call each other.
